# Equal heights of boxes in one row with columns which have more than one box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3.2.0 and the library jQuery-match-height ([GitHub web page](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height)) because I need to have equal height columns.

I created a simple example of my problem with [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d8w2n/1/).

```
$(function() {
    $('.bs-grid-big').matchHeight();
    $('.bs-grid-small').matchHeight();
});
```

I have 1-, 2- or 3-column layout based on the width of the webbrowser window. 1- and 3- column layout works really fine, but not the 2-column layout.

I also created a picture of what I wanted to have:

[image: Image of 2 column layout]

You see three bigger boxes (1, 2 and 3) and three smaller ones (4, 5 and 6) all with dynamic content and font sizes.

The problem is the second row. I want to make boxes 4 and 5 (with margin) as high as box 3 if box 3 is higher than both together. If boxes 4 and 5 are together higher (with margin) than box 3 it should be stretched in height so they are horizontally aligned as shown in my image.

How can I do this?

Comment: you'll need to search for a plugin to help you with this since it cannot be accomplished only by html and css, iam not sure which plugin if i find one i'll comment you the name

Comment: Yes, you are right, with pure HTML and CSS it is infeasible. That's the reason I use `jquery-match-height`.

Comment: http://www.jonathanschmid.de/ext/fluid-isotope/
check this. This might do the need full for you.

This is done using isotope plugin. Check http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ for plugin implementation

Comment: I did it with `jquery-match-height` and some other plugins. It seems to work, but I do not know if it is the best solution: http://jsfiddle.net/rp38Z/5/ Isotope / Masonry won't fit, I already tried it but have also problems with the 2-columns in combination with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

here you go, no need to use a plugin => http://jsfiddle.net/d8w2n/3/

```
$(function() {
    var dummy1=$('.bs-grid-big').eq(0).height();
    var dummy2=$('.bs-grid-big').eq(1).height();
    var dummy3=$('.bs-grid-big').eq(2).height();
    var dummy4=$('.bs-grid-small').eq(0).height();
    var dummy5=$('.bs-grid-small').eq(1).height();
    var dummy6=$('.bs-grid-small').eq(2).height();
    if(dummy1>dummy2){
    $('.bs-grid-big').eq(1).height(dummy1);
    }
    else if(dummy1<dummy2){
    $('.bs-grid-big').eq(0).height(dummy2);
    }
    if(dummy3>(dummy4+dummy5)+40){
    var dummy3Height= dummy3 -40;
        dummy3Height=dummy3Height/2;
        $('.bs-grid-small').eq(0).height(dummy3Height);
        $('.bs-grid-small').eq(1).height(dummy3Height);
    }
    else if(dummy3<(dummy4+5)+40){
    var dummy3Height=(dummy4+dummy5)+40;
        $('.bs-grid-big').eq(2).height(dummy3Height);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I have to do it manually in combination with `jQuery-match-height`. I can not use a fix width which you set to the containers, because it should be fluid / responsive. But I think I have to do your kind of calculation if the 2-column layout is shown.

Comment: Based on your answer, I did this: http://jsfiddle.net/rp38Z/1/ Is this okay? It seems to do what I wanted to have. Maybe you can have a look?

Comment: note that you have to give `.bs-grid-small` and `.bs-grid-big` a fixed width (e.g. 200px in the example I mentioned) and a `float:left;`

Comment: looking at your code, I'm a bit confused 'cause I don't understand what `matchHeight()` is?!

Comment: I mentioned it in my first comment to your answer, it is `jQuery-match-height` plugin. In my latest version (http://jsfiddle.net/rp38Z/5/) I do not need to set a fixed width anymore and the result seems to be okay.

Comment: but in fiddle, the plugin is not available therefor it's not possible for me to see the result, but if it works for you, the code looks good, and I'm glad too! :)

Comment: Hm, for me in Safari, Firefox, Chrome and IE it works fine. Do you get any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: no, it's not the code problem, the problem is with jsfiddle, which doesn't load the plugin you're using, don't worry! ;)